# Can any Script opcode be used in the witness program, or only specific ones?

Tags: segregated-witness, taproot, op-return, opcodes

I was wondering, can one use an OP_RETURN in the witness script? If not, why not? Also, how could I figure this out from reading Bitcoin Core source? I looked at this file, and it wasn't quite clear to me how I might determine which opcodes are allowed in the witness script from this:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/e9262ea32a6e1d364fb7974844fadc36f931f8c6/src/script/script.cpp
But maybe I'm missing something.

I also looked through a couple BIPs, including BIP 143 and BIP 341, but they're kind of beyond my current skill level to understand how they might apply to my question.

Comment: The validation rules of Taproot scripts are specified in BIP342, you might want to check that out.

Comment: @VojtěchStrnad Good thinking, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was wondering, can one use an OP_RETURN in the witness script?

Yes, you can, though I believe it is pointless. Executing an `OP_RETURN` opcode causes the script to return false immediately, marking the spend as invalid. As witness scripts are revealed only at spending time, this can only occur in an unexecuted branch (e.g. `OP_0 OP_IF OP_RETURN OP_ELSE ... OP_ENDIF`, where the `OP_RETURN` does occur in the script but is never hit). So I believe that any script with an `OP_RETURN` in it can be rewritten in a simpler/shorter way without it.

This is different from having an `OP_RETURN` in a scriptPubKey, as scriptPubKeys are revealed at creation time, not at spending time. A scriptPubKey of the form `OP_RETURN <...>` can never be spent (because spending it will cause the scriptPubKey to be executed, and thus fail), but it doesn't prevent the output from existing.

> I looked at this file, and it wasn't quite clear to me how I might determine which opcodes are allowed in the witness script from this:

The `script/script.{h,cpp}` files only define the `CScript` data structure and some related functions. The validation rules regarding script execution are in `script/interpreter.{h,cpp}`.

> I also looked through a couple BIPs, including BIP 143 and BIP 341, but they're kind of beyond my current skill level to understand how they might apply to my question.

[BIP141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki) introduced segwit outputs, scriptPubKeys or P2SH redeemScripts of the form `OP_n <witness program>`, and permitted a new type of inputs (segwit inputs, which spend such outputs) which provide witness data not in the normal scriptSig, but in a new segregated witness section of the transaction data. As of today, there are 3 separate types of such outputs, each with their own validation rules:

- Also introduced in [BIP141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki), P2WPKH outputs have a scriptPubKey or redeemScript of the form `OP_0 <20-byte hash>`, where the hash is a public key hash. These outputs can be spent by revealing the full public key plus a signature with that key. No "real" script (with user-chosen opcodes) is ever revealed. The signature hash for these signatures is in BIP143.
- Also introduced in [BIP141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki), P2WSH outputs have a scriptPubkey or redeemScript of the form `OP_0 <32-byte hash>`, where the hash is a script hash. These outputs can be spent by revealing the full script (called the witness script), plus inputs to that witness script that make it evaluate to true. The semantics of scripts here only differs very slightly from the normal scriptPubKey script validation rules (which predate the BIP process), including for `OP_RETURN`. See the BIP under ["New script semantics"](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#new-script-semantics) for details.
- Introduced in [BIP341](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki) are taproot outputs; scriptPubKeys of the form `OP_1 <32-byte x-only pubkey>`. Each of these can be spent in two different ways:

  - Using a key-path spend (also introduced in [BIP341](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki)). This involves *just* a signature (using a Schnorr signature instead of an ECDSA signature, defined in [BIP340](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki)), and no script execution of any type is involved.
  - Using a script-path spend (also introduced in [BIP341](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki)). This involves revealing one of the scripts the taproot output committed to, together with a script version number. [BIP341](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki) however leaves the semantics of these scripts unspecified.

    - [BIP342](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0342.mediawiki) specifies the script semantics for taproot script-path spends with script version 0xc0, called tapscripts. They are mostly the same as the P2WSH script validation rules, but there are more differences than BIP141 had compared to legacy scripts. The major differences include [BIP340](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0340.mediawiki) signatures, a new sighash scheme (mostly reusing the [BIP341](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0341.mediawiki) one, but with a few extensions), the removal of `OP_CHECKMULTISIG` and `OP_CHECKMULTIVSIGERIFY`, the introduction of `OP_CHECKSIGADD`, new resource limitations, and a few miscellaneous changes. `OP_RETURN` is not affected.
    - taproot script path spends with a script version number other than 0xc0 don't have any script semantics associated with them (yet), and are anyone-can-spend (but nonstandard).
- scriptPubKeys and redeemScripts of the form `OP_n <witness program>`, where n is between 1 and 16, excluding taproot outputs, don't have any script semantics (yet). They're anyone can spend, but non-standard.

Regarding terminology:

- The **witness program** is the 20-byte or 32-byte data element (pubkey hash, script hash, or x-only public key) pushed after OP_0 or OP_1 in the segwit scriptPubKey or redeemScript.
- The **witness script** is the script revealed in a P2WSH spend.
- The revealed script in a BIP342 spend is called the **tapscript**.